# Styling woocommerce description

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, styling

I'm creating this site http://pmgoalkeeperacademy.com/wordpress/ and am running into a big problem! There is 2 descriptions in the "Product" page, 1 above the tabs and 1 inside the tabs. I need to get the text color in the "tab" section to black. I have found out that if I change the colour of the body text that effects the tab but this is where the problem is. If I make the text colour black I can't see the text above it and if I make it white I can't see the text below it.

I need a way to separate the styling for the p tags.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Rather than linking to your site and expecting us to wade through your code, please provide a Snippet or Fiddle of the code relevant to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more references/fiddles provided you shouldn't expect this to work site-wide, but I think adding the following to your stylesheet should solve the issue:

```
body.single-product div.panel.entry-content p { color: #000 }
```